# How to load pure JS file using ruby gem commonjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby, commonjs, execjs

**Simple question:** how to load pure .js file from ruby?

My current strategy is to load a .js file from within ruby is to use the [commonjs gem](https://github.com/cowboyd/commonjs.rb). I recognize that the instructions are to load the **js directory** and then require the **file**.  Unfortunately, I keep getting a TypeError when I try to load the directory for trying to convert nil to string.

Here's my file structure:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── lib
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── data.json
│   │   │   ├── expressions.js
│   │   │   └── javascript_i_want_to_run.js
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── example.rb
├── example.gemspec
├── script
└── test
```

Following the [commonjs instructions](https://github.com/cowboyd/commonjs.rb#using-common-js-from-ruby), here is the failure I get when invoking from pry (notice I'm loading the *directory* not the *file*).

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'commonjs'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> env = CommonJS::Environment.new(path: 'lib/example/js')
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/commonjs-0.2.7/lib/commonjs/environment.rb:9:in `initialize'
```

I'm stumped.  Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in readme. The first parameter in `initialize` method of `CommonJS::Environment` class is `runtime`. It should be:

```
require 'commonjs'
require 'v8'

runtime = V8::Context.new
env = CommonJS::Environment.new(runtime, path: 'lib/example/js')
```